# NSec.Cryptography encrypt and decrypt using ChaCha20Poly1305 and SharedSecret

Tags: c#, encryption, cryptography, libsodium, shared-secret

I'm trying to encrypt (and decrypt) messages send from one device to another by using NSec.Cryptography, but I find the documentation a bit vague. As I understood I need a `Key` and `PublicKey` of device A and B, respectively. I can turn these into a `SharedSecret`:

```cs
var sharedSecret = KeyAgreementAlgorithm.X25519.Agree(encryption.Key, deviceKey);
```

However, this shared secret doesn't seem useful for encryption as the `Encrypt(...)` method asks for a Key in its parameters:

```cs
var cyphertext = AeadAlgorithm.ChaCha20Poly1305.Encrypt(sharedSecret, nonce, new byte[0], message);
                                                              ^-- will not work
```

I have multiple questions:

1. What is the use of SharedSecret if it can not be used to encrypt?
2. How is the `ChaCha20Poly1305.Encrypt` method useful if it uses one key which can't be a shared secret?
3. How do I encrypt a message using the private key of A and public key of B (like box and secret box in libsodium)?

Note: I wanna use X25519 keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the documentation for `SharedSecret`:

> **Represents the output of a [key agreement](https://nsec.rocks/docs/api/nsec.cryptography.keyagreementalgorithm) and the input for [key derivation](https://nsec.rocks/docs/api/nsec.cryptography.keyderivationalgorithm)**

So you first need to generate one or more keys using a specific KDF and NSec seems to implement HKDF (using SHA-256 or-512, I'd prefer the latter because it is more secure and - on 64 bit machines - possibly even faster. The shared secret itself is not fully random to an adversary, so a KDF is required to create the most cryptographically secure keys from it.

This should answer 1 & 2: `SharedSecret` is used to derive the actual keys, it isn't a key in itself.

> How do I encrypt a message using the private key of A and public key of B (like box and secret box in libsodium)?

As for 3: You need an *ephemeral key pair* on the sender A and the public key of receiver B. Then you perform the key agreement & key derivation (as above) using the sender's ephemeral private key and send the ephemeral public key with the ciphertext. Don't forget to destroy the ephemeral private key of the sender after the key agreement; you don't need it anymore, and leaking it will compromise the ciphertext.

The receiver can now perform the same agreement using their static private key and the received ephemeral public key, and finally decrypt the message.

Comment: Right, so there is an extra layer that libsodium and the likes usually hide it seems. Will try that today and update the answer accordingly! Thanks for the help.